# Problems with tests on selenium hub and kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, webdriver, selenium-ide

I have a problem with Kubernetes and Selenium side runner. I started the Selenium hub as service on cluster k8s. I have 2 nodes, one with Firefox browser and the other one with Chrome browser, I should perform tests using selenium-side-runner starting all from local, pointing to hub selenium nodes. Unfortunately I can't really understand how or what is the right URL for each knot to perform tests.

Can you help me, please?

I attach a screenshot of my current situation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxxix.png)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<selenium_hub_svc_name>.<selenium_namespace>:<selenium_hub_svc_port>`. This will use k8s internal DNS https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services